# request.getParameter("f") evaluates to null

Tags: java, liferay

I hooked Liferay's login.jsp and I am redirecting to the url `localhost:8080?f=0`. In this case `login.jsp` is invoked for sure. But I could not get the parameter value of f as 0. Instead I got its value as `null`. I am printing value of f as `request.getParameter("f")`.

Here I want to do some task based on the value of f but it evaluates to `null` everytime. How could I get the request parameter in `login.jsp`?

Comment: Did you try with `ParamUtil.getString(request, "f")`?

Comment: Have you tried localhost:8080/login.jsp?f=0

Comment: I tried printing ParamUtil.getString(request, "f") but nothing gets printed

Comment: Are all of those "Abhishek Jain" accounts that pop up recently you? How many accounts do you entertain? Please mention Liferay explicitly in your next questions (I'm editing this) because otherwise you'll mislead the servlet crowd: The answer in the portlet world is completely different.

Comment: @Olaf: Please tell me the answer in the portlet world..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` in a portal's JSP is a servlet request, but not necessarily the one *actually* used for this request (by the appserver). For this working in Liferay's context, try the variations of `PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest` and `PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest`. You might need `renderRequest` instead of `request`. Just trying, not sure if this will actually solve:

```
PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(
   PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest));
```

Alternatively you might try

```
PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(request);
```

Again, I'm not 100% sure any of these will work, because I can't imagine what you're intending to do. Somehow I also sense that there's a better solution for your undisclosed underlying problem.

Some more background:

In the portal world, you're typically well shielded from the original HttpServletRequest, instead you're getting access to request objects matching your current lifecycle phase, e.g. `renderRequest`. The JSP spec however assumes that you *always* have access to a `request` object that implements `ServletRequest` - `renderRequest` however implements `PortletRequest`, and while both are similar, they're distinct unrelated interfaces. So technically you must have access to a `request` object (due to the spec) when you're on a JSP. However, as you do know that this JSP is called from a portlet context, you can't really make use of it. The workaround that I've given is Liferay's proprietary API method to gain back control over the appserver's request. It's not good style to make use of it, but sometimes just gets the job done.

Comment: PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(request)  worked...thanks Olaf..you are amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with your url. If you are using jsp-servlet programming for your web application then correct url would be :

```
http://localhost:8080/<AppName>/<Servlet/JSP>?f=0
```

1. `<AppName>` is nothing but your project name.
2. `<Servlet/JSP>` is nothing but your servlet/jsp page name.

e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/Test/index.jsp
```

Above is example of my url for JSP-Servlet WebApp.

Comment: You can not call any webapp using only localhost url

Answer (score 0):

Your url is wrong. It must be `http://localhost:8080/login.jsp?f=0`.
If you dont want to show your url, you can use friendly url to resolve it.